# Looping failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to make the program loop until the user inputs "XXXX" as the name. Problem is, my code only loops once at most and exits. I have tried messing with do ... whiles for an entire day and can't seem to figure this out but I feel like i'm really close!

**Edit:** 
You guys are awesome! Made both of the changes but now it skips the name prompt and goes straight to the deposit prompt. How would i get it to include the name prompt in the loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string name, XXXX;
float deposit, time, interest, total, totinterest;
int compound;

cout << left;

int flag = 0;

do {

    cout << "Enter your name or XXXX to stop: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << name << " enter the following information: " << endl;


    if (name == "XXXX"){
        flag = 1;
    }else 
    {

        cout << setw(60) << "\tAmount on deposit: ";
        cin >> deposit;
        if (!deposit || deposit < 0){
            cout << "\tPlease enter a positive number! ";

        }

        cout << setw(60) << "\tYears on deposit: ";
        cin >> time;
        if (!time || time < 0){
            cout << "\tPlease enter a positive number! ";
            return(0);
        }

        cout << setw(60) << "\tNumber of times the interest is compounded per year: ";
        cin >> compound;
        if (!compound || compound < 0){
            cout << "\tPlease enter a positive number! ";
            return(0);
        }

        if (time >= 5)
            interest = .045;
        else if (time >= 4)
            interest = .04;
        else if (time >= 3)
            interest = .035;
        else if (time >= 2)
            interest = .025;
        else if (time >= 1)
            interest = .02;
        else if (time < 1)
            interest = .015;

        total = (deposit)*pow((1 + interest / compound), (compound * time));
        totinterest = total - deposit;

        cout << left << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << endl;
        cout << setw(15) << "Name " << setw(14) << "Years" << setw(18) << "Deposit Amount" << setw(18) << "Interest Earned " << setw(18) << "Total" << endl;
        cout << "===============================================================================" << endl;
        cout << setw(15) << name << setw(14) << time << setw(1) << "$" << setw(17) << deposit << setw(1) << "$" << setw(17) << totinterest << setw(1) << "$" << setw(18) << total << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Thank you for using tax program. Have a nice day. " << endl;
        return(0);

    }

} while (flag = 0);

}
```

Comment: Use `continue;` instead of `return(0);`

Comment: Here is it running http://cpp.sh/5ggh

Comment: By the way if you enter text instead of an amount an infinite loop occurs. This seems to happen on the second or greater iteration of the while loop

Comment: Do you know how i would be able to have the program reprompt me for my name with every loop? It currently skips that part and goes straight to the deposit part.

Comment: Skips on first iteration or subsequent iterations?

Comment: Normally when I see a C or C++ program skipping input it's almost always a new line in the buffer. There's tons of questions on here about how to fix that. The easiest to implement is to loop the name prompt until the name variable isn't empty.

Comment: It skips on subsequent iterations

Comment: Before your `getline`, add `cin >> ws`, or a call to `ignore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `return(0);` in your else clause. Also, you have `=` instead of `==` in your while loop, which (after you remove the return statement) is a recipe for an infinite loop.

Comment: Made both of the changes but now it skips the name prompt and goes straight to the deposit prompt. How would i get it to include the name prompt int he loop?

Comment: @TheeOomer: is this on the first iteration or on subsequent iterations?

Comment: Subsequent. The first part is exactly how i want it, but it skips the name prompt on subsequent iterations.

Comment: @TheeOomer: What I figured. Pseudocode: `do {cout<<"Enter name" << endl; getline(cin, name); } while(name=="");`

Comment: **−1** "is a recipe for an infinite loop" is incorrect, and Ron changed it back to that after I fixed it for him. Jeez.

Comment: @Cheers: Didn't mean to change it back lol, sorry. Was trying to fix it with better wording.

Answer (score 5):

return(0) will get you out of the main. Remove that line and retry.

Answer (score 5):

`return(0)` will exit the `main()` and the program will terminate. Hence, remove it from the source.

Also the condition in `while (flag = 0)` will always return `false`. Change it to `while (flag == 0)` otherwise it would result in a *loop that iterates only once*.

And finally, you need `<math.h>` for the `pow()` function.

```
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: Regarding the `<cmath>`, as of C++11 and later it does not even have a formal advantage over plain `<math.h>`, and does potentially lead to some portability problems. Therefore it's a good idea to use original C library `<math.h>` instead. However, it hardly matters for a student's exercise, which will not probably not be ported anyway; there are or were some bugs in the g++ headers (I do not recall this exactly, but it's there in SO questions about this); and for some beginners it can be more important to feel that they're going with the perceived spirit of C++.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using `=` instead of `==` in `while` condition.

Change `flag = 0` to `!flag` or `flag==0`.

Apart from this, you have `return 0` which is unconditional. This return statement will make the program to exit anyhow.

Comment: This would only cause an infinite loop, not what he's seeing. However, it would be apparent once he fixes his return statement, so have an upvote anyway.

Comment: Made both of the changes but now it skips the name prompt and goes straight to the deposit prompt. How would i get it to include the name prompt int he loop?

Answer (score 3):

You have to include

```
#include <math.h>
```

for your pow function to work. I get an error that pow is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you want your while condition to be 
`while(flag == 0)` and not `while (flag = 0)`

Also, if the user enters an invalid value of time or deposit or compound(such as less than 0), then your code prints out an error message and quits. Instead, you want to put a while loop there that keeps prompting the user for a valid input as long they keep giving an incorrect input.

Finally, you wanna be using something like `myString.compare(otherString)` instead of the == operator

Comment: Agreed and as I mentioned before invalid values trigger an infinite loop when the ivalid value is entered on the second or greater iteration and you can't change the customer name either.

Comment: Re "you wanna be using something like myString.compare(otherString) instead of the == operator", no, it has no advantage, and the disadvantages of being less clear and more verbose.

Comment: That's probably a Java-ism, where you **must** do that.